# Can i18n be applied to emberjs TextFields/Labels etc.?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, handlebars.js, rails-i18n

Is there a way to use i18n on ember/emberjs-bootstrap TextField labels.

For example

```
{{view "Bootstrap.Forms.TextField"  valueBinding="account.email" label={{t 'account.email'}}}}
```

This would not work, but I am looking for something if its possible via Handlebars syntax, without me needing to extend each element I want to support i18n.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're using [Ember-i18n](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n) already, but it has a good integration with Ember and seems to be a good start to build on or extend. Here are some simple examples, one using interpolated data.

```
<h2>{{t user.edit.title}}</h2>

<h2>{{t user.followers.title count="2"}}</h2>
```

And you keys are defined as

```
Em.I18n.translations = {
  'user.edit.title': 'Edit User',
  'user.followers.title.one': 'One Follower',
  'user.followers.title.other': 'All {{count}} Followers',
  'button.add_user.title': 'Add a user',
  'button.add_user.text': 'Add',
  'button.add_user.disabled': 'Saving...'
};
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I am using this its good but my question is I want to use translations inside TextField view the way I mentioned. I know I can extend it and write the label to use the translations but if there is a direct way to mention label as {{t user.edit.title}}. Please take a peek at code mentioned in question.

Comment: Effectively my questions falls in handlebars not precisely EmberJS https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/222

Answer (score 0):

I am using this as a work around, which is no where close to elegant.

```
{{#T frontend.signup.name}}
{{view "Bootstrap.Forms.TextField"  valueBinding="account.name"  label=i18Label}}
{{/T}}

Handlebars.registerHelper "T", (key, options) ->
 ret = options.fn( i18Label: I18n.t(key) )
```

Usually I get a case of one string at a time. Only other way is to extend TextField views.